# PhpStorm, SASS and autoprefixer

Tags: ruby, sass, phpstorm, autoprefixer

I have PhpStorm with [SASS compiler](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html), works perfect. Now I try to add [autoprefixer](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails#compass), but it is not working. The gem is installed, in `...\Ruby23-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.3.0\gems\autoprefixer-rails-6.3.6\spec\compass\config.rb` the hook is inserted (as described in the last link).

After saving SASS file in PhpStorm, a CSS file is created, but without prefixes (tried with flexbox, transform...). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure I understand your configuration... Do you use Sass compiler, or Compass? In the latter case, does autoprefixer run after compass compile when being called from command line (system terminal)? In the first case, why do you expect the compass  post-compile hook to work with your compiler?

Comment: I'd actually suggest using Gulp/Grunt here - you can use them for compiling sass and adding prefixes

Comment: @lena Sass compiler (transpiler to be correct) configured in File Watcher (as described in PhpStorm manual). I'll check config again and try Gulp/Grunt. Thanks.

Comment: you can't expect sass compiler to work with compass hooks... The way sass compiler is set up in PHPStorm doesn't matter here